# Bigquery SQL : When to use Aggregated Function over Analytics Function over Subquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery, aggregate-functions, analytic-functions

Let's say i have a table with Users :

| user_id |
| --- |
| abc |
| def |

And a table of Purchases :

| purchase_id | purchase_date | status | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | sold | abc |
| 2 | 2020-02-01 | refunded | abc |
| 3 | 2020-03-01 | sold | def |
| 4 | 2020-04-01 | sold | def |
| 5 | 2020-05-01 | sold | def |

I want the status of the last purchase for each user, which would be :

| user_id | last_purchase_date | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2020-02-01 | refunded |
| def | 2020-05-01 | sold |

I am wondering what is the **best approach** (in term of performance, cost, readability ...) between those three queries that give the same results :

**Aggregated Function**

```
SELECT 
  user_id,
  MAX(purchase_date) as last_purchase_date,
  ARRAY_AGG(status ORDER BY purchase_date DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] as last_status
FROM user
LEFT JOIN purchase USING (user_id)
GROUP BY user_id
```

**Analytics Function**

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  user_id,
  MAX(purchase_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) as last_purchase_date,
  LAST_VALUE(status) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY purchase_date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as last_status,
FROM user
LEFT JOIN purchase USING (user_id)
```

**Subquery**

```
SELECT 
  user_id,
  purchase_date as last_purchase_date,
  status as last_status
FROM user
LEFT JOIN purchase USING (user_id)
WHERE purchase_date IN (
  SELECT 
    MAX(purchase_date) as purchase_date
  FROM purchase
  GROUP BY user_id
)
```

Here is the Dataset for those who want it :

```
WITH purchase as (
  SELECT 1 as purchase_id, "2020-01-01" as purchase_date, "sold" as status, "abc" as user_id
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 as purchase_id, "2020-02-01" as purchase_date, "refunded" as status, "abc" as user_id
  UNION ALL SELECT 3 as purchase_id, "2020-03-01" as purchase_date, "sold" as status, "def" as user_id
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 as purchase_id, "2020-04-01" as purchase_date, "sold" as status, "def" as user_id
  UNION ALL SELECT 5 as purchase_id, "2020-05-01" as purchase_date, "sold" as status, "def" as user_id
), user as (
    SELECT "abc" as user_id,
    UNION ALL SELECT "def" as user_id,
)
```

Comment: You can see de difference by yourself running both queries and looking at the "excecution details" tab.

Comment: I have done it for all of them and it's not that clear. So i'm wondering which approach looks the more natural? Is that common to do a DISTINCT in a Analytics Function instead of going for an Aggregated Function? Why does Aggregated Function and Analytics Function performs quite the same while 
it seems that an Analytics Function should be doing way more work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple: always use the most performing and cheapest approach.

When you run your code snippets with the provided test data you can see in the execution details which one is better for this use case:

**Aggregated Function**
[image]

**Analytics Function**
[image]

As you can see the aggregated function consumed around 3 times less slot time and shuffled less bytes than the analytics function. That means for this use case it is much better to use your aggregate function then the analytical one.

The power of analytical functions comes when you have use cases where you cannot use aggregate functions and can only be solved with analytical functions. Analytical functions have a wider range of application than other types of functions.